# How do I determine which process is using more physical memory?

Tags: memory-usage

I've already run `free -t -m` and `ps aux --sort -rss`, but I don't understand why there's a difference between the output of these two commands regarding the amount of total physical memory currently being used. The outputs are as follows.

`# free -t -m`

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           995        863        132          0         30        658
-/+ buffers/cache:        173        821
Swap:            0          0          0
Total:         995        863        132
```

`# ps aux --sort -rss`

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
mysql      824  0.0  6.1 887776 63128 ?        Ssl  Feb24   0:35 /usr/sbin/mysqld
www-data  1411  0.0  1.5 235640 15696 ?        S    Feb24   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1349  0.0  1.5 238744 15300 ?        S    Feb24   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1158  0.0  1.4 238308 14812 ?        S    Feb24   0:02 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1412  0.0  1.4 238264 14764 ?        S    Feb24   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data   906  0.0  1.3 234120 14200 ?        S    Feb24   0:02 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  2673  0.0  1.3 234096 14044 ?        S    12:52   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1413  0.0  1.2 236368 12916 ?        S    Feb24   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  2577  0.0  1.1 232496 12184 ?        S    10:54   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1484  0.0  1.1 232180 12028 ?        S    Feb24   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  2675  0.0  1.1 231924 11704 ?        S    12:53   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root       867  0.0  0.9 229388  9888 ?        Ss   Feb24   0:03 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root      2939  0.0  0.4  88304  4084 ?        Ss   16:20   0:00 sshd: root@pts/0    
root      1023  0.0  0.3 584428  3840 ?        Sl   Feb24   0:00 /usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon --no-daemon
root      2956  0.0  0.3  21872  3148 pts/0    Ss   16:20   0:00 -bash
root       620  0.0  0.2  52252  2836 ?        Ss   Feb24   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
root         1  0.0  0.2  26756  2428 ?        Ss   Feb24   0:00 /sbin/init
syslog     428  0.0  0.1 247456  1560 ?        Sl   Feb24   0:01 rsyslogd -c5
root      3094  0.0  0.1  18600  1300 pts/0    R+   17:06   0:00 ps aux --sort -rss
root       316  0.0  0.1  21552  1272 ?        Ss   Feb24   0:00 /sbin/udevd --daemon
102        408  0.0  0.1  24004  1140 ?        Ss   Feb24   0:00 dbus-daemon --system --fork
root       766  0.0  0.1  21324  1028 ?        Ss   Feb24   0:00 cron
root       725  0.0  0.0  15828   976 tty5     Ss+  Feb24   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty5
root       739  0.0  0.0  15828   976 tty3     Ss+  Feb24   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty3
root       743  0.0  0.0  15828   976 tty6     Ss+  Feb24   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty6
root       719  0.0  0.0  15828   972 tty4     Ss+  Feb24   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty4
root       735  0.0  0.0  15828   964 tty2     Ss+  Feb24   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty2
root       900  0.0  0.0  15828   960 tty1     Ss+  Feb24   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
root       453  0.0  0.0  21548   816 ?        S    Feb24   0:00 /sbin/udevd --daemon
root       454  0.0  0.0  21548   816 ?        S    Feb24   0:00 /sbin/udevd --daemon
root       763  0.0  0.0   4376   684 ?        Ss   Feb24   0:00 acpid -c /etc/acpi/events -s /var/run/acpid.socket
root       313  0.0  0.0  17316   636 ?        S    Feb24   0:00 upstart-udev-bridge --daemon
root       303  0.0  0.0  15268   412 ?        S    Feb24   0:00 upstart-file-bridge --daemon
root       600  0.0  0.0  15256   412 ?        S    Feb24   0:00 upstart-socket-bridge --daemon
daemon     767  0.0  0.0  19124   168 ?        Ss   Feb24   0:00 atd
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb24   0:00 [kthreadd]
```

I've got 243068 KB (237 MB) as the sum of RSS column and the free command shows 863 MB being used. Am I doing something wrong? Can I assume the MySQL as the main process consuming the physical memory, despite the big difference? Is it really using 63128 KB (61 MB)?

**UPDATE****

Very nice website explaining how to interpret the `free -t -m` output: http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Comment: Well... if you subtract "cached" from "used" in the output from `free` you get pretty close right? I think the source of the confusion here is Linux tendency to "reserve" RAM without using it.

Comment: Yes, I would like someone explain me that difference or at least give me the reference to read more about. I feel really confused with these concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code to list processes and there memory usage from smaller to greater usage size .

```
sudo ps -e -orss=,args= | sort -b -k1,1n
```

[image]

( you can add **,pid=** if you want the process id )

You can learn about ps command [Here](http://ss64.com/bash/ps_keywords.html)

If you want graphically :

In dash , type **System Monitor** .

press **Processes Tab**

You can see each process by its memory usage under **Memory**

Press on **Memory** to sort them by **Increasing** order or **decreasing**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I found this website (http://www.linuxatemyram.com/) and it helped me a lot to understand what cache memory does.